# apache2 with mod_proxy stopped redirect virtualhosts

Tags: virtualhost, apache2, mod-proxy

I'm using apache to redirect requests for another server.  a week ago we had replaced the router of the office, later on the redirection had stopped.  (virtual hosts on same machine still works.  redirect virtual hosts to another machine doesn't).  this hapens even if I try it inside office (bypassing the new router).
OS - current ubuntu (made full update after the problem started when I tried to solve it).
It used to work since 2015 and untill May the 23 2019.

the relative lines in the apache2.conf are :

```
LoadModule proxy_module lib/apache/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module lib/apache/mod_proxy_http.so
#two lines above are meaningless on current version of apache (modules were loaded earlier).


#------------------------------------------
#browsing to thisDomain:80 gots to /var/www/html/ as it should go

#------------------------------------------
#next definition goes to /var/www/html instead of it's destination!
<virtualHost demo1.thisDomain:80>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.3:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.3:80/
</virtualHost>

#------------------------------------------
#next goes to it's destination as it should /var/www/html/guy
<virtualHost local1.thisDomain:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/guy/
</virtualHost>
```

Comment: It doesn't work - without an actual error message - makes for nigh impossible to answer questions. (e.g. what does `curl -v http://192.168.0.3:80/` from your apache host show)  _--_ SoHo routers typically provide many roles in small networks and any of them may have changed resulting in your problems. Think missing NAT / port-forarding rules, changed network config and DHCP scope , different DNS and resolving ...

Comment: @HBruijn  - If i try to browes directly to http://192.168.0.3:80/ - no error (I've tried it from the server, using Firefox and dillo).  curl -v http://192.168.0.3:80/ returns to me the index.html from the right server without any problem.

Comment: By using `<virtualHost demo1.thisDomain:80>` and `<virtualHost local1.thisDomain:80>` you are configuring IP based virtual hosts, name based virtual hosting requires inclusion of a ServerName directive and typically uses   `<virtualHost *:80>` directives. See  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts

Comment: Hi  HBruijn, If i forgot to say - It used to work since 2015 and untill May the 23 2019..  (We had replaced the router at office).